# Shopify App Billing API: How to offer multiple billing plans?

Tags: shopify, billing, shopify-app, shopify-api

Shopify's recent July 2020 API update allows billing annually for apps, so I've been trying to add the option to choose between monthly and annual billing to my app.

I've been trying to do this by modifying the GraphQL call that creates the billing plan.

I've been trying several different options, but the most logical one seems to be to add an additional line item. This works in rendering both plans to the billing approval screen, but it is still not possible to actually choose between plans (details for both plans are displayed, but only the latter option is actually effective.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
  const query = JSON.stringify({
    query: `mutation {
      appSubscriptionCreate(
          name: "Basic Plan"
          trialDays: 7
          returnUrl: "${process.env.HOST}"
          lineItems: [
          {
            plan: {
              appRecurringPricingDetails: {
                  price: { amount: 4.99, currencyCode: USD }
              }
            }
            plan: {
              appRecurringPricingDetails: {
                  price: { amount: 49.99, currencyCode: USD }
                  interval: ANNUAL
              }
            }
          }
          ]
        ) {
            userErrors {
              field
              message
            }
            confirmationUrl
            appSubscription {
              id
            }
        }
    }`
  });
```

I'd be happy about any suggestions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried setting the interval for the first one to EVERY_30_DAYS to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but result is the same. If no interval is given, it defaults to EVERY_30_DAYS.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? Any updates would be helpful

Comment: I tried your graphql mutation but I got this error. `{"errors":[{"message":"There can be only one input field named \"plan\"","locations":[{"line":8,"column":13},{"line":13,"column":13}],"path":["mutation","appSubscriptionCreate","lineItems",0],"extensions":{"code":"inputFieldNotUnique","name":"plan"}}]}`. How could you get it to render multiple subscription line item on the payment page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include both **monthly** and **annual** plans in `appSubscriptionCreate` mutation.

You should store available plans(**monthly** and **annual**) in the database and show the plans page for the customers to choose from.

If the customer chooses **monthly**, you can create an app subscription with a **monthly** plan:

```js
const query = JSON.stringify({
  query: `mutation {
    appSubscriptionCreate(
        // other fields
        lineItems: [
          {
            plan: {
              appRecurringPricingDetails: {
                  price: { amount: 4.99, currencyCode: USD }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ) {
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
          confirmationUrl
          appSubscription {
            id
          }
      }
  }`
});
```

If the customer chooses **annual**, you can create an app subscription with a **annual** plan:

```js
const query = JSON.stringify({
  query: `mutation {
    appSubscriptionCreate(
        // other fields
        lineItems: [
          {
            plan: {
              appRecurringPricingDetails: {
                price: { amount: 49.99, currencyCode: USD }
                interval: ANNUAL
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ) {
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
          confirmationUrl
          appSubscription {
            id
          }
      }
  }`
});
```

Please don't forget to include a discount for the **annual** plan.